# GMT conversion wrong at 12am

Tags: java, xml, date

OK so i've used some posts on stackoverflow to get a conversion semi-working for some XML data.

In the XML data feed, I get a date and a time, as SEPARATE elements - they are in GMT time.

So in order to convert it and compare to local time, i'm doing the following ("ne" contains my object from XML feed):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(myTimeZone.getDisplayName()));

Date newdate = sdf.parse(ne.getNewsDate().toString() + " " + ne.getNewsTime().toString());

if (newdate.before(new Date())) 
    //don't use
else 
    //use
```

So as an example of a date/time from XML feed that is wrongly converting, let's take:

```
<date>
<![CDATA[ 12-02-2014 ]]>
</date>
<time>
<![CDATA[ 12:00am ]]>
</time>
```

"newdate" above is returning "Tue Dec 02 23:00:00 AEDT 2014", when my system clock reads 2/12/2014 3:00PM"
So clearly, it is converting the GMT time of 12-02-2014 12:00am, incorrectly as a time in the future, whereas I need it to realise it is in the past.

So where I am confused is that it is correctly converting for MOST of the date/time from the feed, but certain ones as above are incorrect.

I hope that makes sense, so basically I am trying to ignore date/times from the XML feed that are gone, by converting the two SEPARATE date/time fields into my local time, and then checking to see if its past or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`HH` is the date format for 24-hour dates,](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and you haven't passed an am/pm marker placeholder in the date format string. Try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mma");
```

**N.B.** `SimpleDateFormat` might not recognize lowercase (`"am"`) as `"AM"` for the am/pm marker, so you *might* need to call `String#toUpperCase()`:

```
Date newdate = sdf.parse(ne.getNewsDate().toString() + " " + ne.getNewsTime().toString().toUpperCase());
```

Comment: man i am loving this site ! answers are spot on and timely !  Thx - I didn't need the toUpperCase, just the hh:mma Perfect!